# How do I convert BAM to FASTQ in pipe to analyze and then remove the fastq generated?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

Sorry for this question but I am a bioinformatician with not much programming experience and I don't know how to fix it.

I have several bam files in a server directory. I would like to count with `grep` the number of occurrences both in the bam and in the corrisponding fastq file but, due to the lack of space, I also need to remove each fastq file after the analysis.

To count the number of occurrences in the BAM I tried with this (but any suggestions are welcome):

```
for i in *bam* ; do
    echo $i >> TELO_BAM
    grep 'TTAGGG' $i |
    wc -l >> TELO_BAM 
done
```

As you can see I also wanted to put the file name and the count in a txt file.

Now, to count the number in a fastq I tried with this but I don't know how to delete the fastq as soon as I've done the count (so it doesn't take up space):

```
for i in *bam*; do
    samtools bam2fq $i >> $i\.fq |
    echo $i >> TELO_FQ
    grep 'TTAGGG' $i >> TELO_FQ
done
```

I don't know if it works, but I would like to convert the bam to fastq, put the filename in a text file, count the occurrences in the fastq and then delete it and move on to the next file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `grep XXX | wc -l` gives you the number of lines that contain `XXX`, not the number of occurrences (unless each line can contain at most one occurrence).
  With GNU `grep -o XXX | wc -l` you'll be able to count the total number of occurrences.
- Using `>> TELO_XXX` inside the loops is sub-optimal, it's better to use a file descriptor.
- <s>You name the FastQ file `$i.fq`, so you just have to `rm "$i.fq"` after using it.</s> No need to create any FastQ file; `samtools bam2fq` writes its output to stdout so you can `grep` it directly.

Here's an **untested** code illustrating all that:

```sh
exec 3> TELO_BAM || exit 1
exec 4> TELO_FQ  || exit 1

for bam in *bam*
do
    printf '%s: ' "$bam" 1>&3
    grep -o 'TTAGGG' "$bam" | wc -l 1>&3

    printf '%s: ' "$bam.fq" 1>&4
    samtools bam2fq "$bam" | grep -o 'TTAGGG' | wc -l 1>&4
done
```

Comment: Of course, there is no need to save the output file. Just pipe the `samtools` output to `grep`